# Can't animate wireframe rotation in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I tried to make the wireframe rotate in the scene.

The animation works when I removed the BoxHelper, but I want to animate the cube wireframe without diagonal line instead of a solid object.

---

#### Codepen demo :

[**Demo**](http://codepen.io/helenfung/pen/jWeLPe?editors=0010)

---

#### Code :

```
var  w = window.innerWidth, h = window.innerHeight,
scene = new THREE.Scene(), 
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, w/h, 0.1, 1000),
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer(),
geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 ),
material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } ),
mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material ),
cube = new THREE.BoxHelper(mesh);

cube.material.color.setRGB(25,25,25);
scene.add(cube);

camera.position.z = 2;
renderer.setSize(w,h);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);


function render(){
  requestAnimationFrame( render );
  cube.rotation.x += 1;
  renderer.render(scene, camera );
}

render();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The position of your `THREE.BoxHelper` instance is tied to the position of the `THREE.Mesh`. For your code to work you will have to add the mesh to the scene and rotate the mesh. Your box helper will follow.

If you don't want to show the mesh you can simply set `mesh.visible = false;`

This code works:

```
var w = window.innerWidth, h = window.innerHeight,
    scene = new THREE.Scene(), 
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, w/h, 0.1, 1000),
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer(),
    geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 ),
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry );

camera.position.z = 2;  
renderer.setSize(w,h);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

mesh.visible = false; //<-- hide mesh
scene.add(mesh);      //<-- add mesh to scene

cube = new THREE.BoxHelper(mesh);   
cube.material.color.setRGB(25,25,25);
scene.add(cube);

function render(){
    mesh.rotation.y += 0.01; //<-- rotate the mesh

    requestAnimationFrame( render );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}

render();
```